# Kali Linux always boots in grub

Tags: boot, kali-linux, grub

I've installed my Kali Linux several times, but I boot into grub. Then I have to use the following code to get into the OS;

```
set prefix=(hd0,gpt2)/boot/grub
set boot=(hd0,gpt2)
insmod normal
normal
```

As this is quite inconvenient, I googled how to change my boot configuration and I found the following solution:

> sudo nano /etc/default/grub
> Locate`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and set the boot parameters as needed. If you need to load a module with "insmod," you can do so like this
>
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
>
> Then `sudo update-grub`

I tried to add  the prefix and boot commands separated by semicolons but I ended up in grub once again having to manually boot. Thankfully recovery worked. Then I added the insmod normal and normal command as well but then it wouldn't boot (even in recovery).

So I'm wondering where I'm going wrong, and if anyone has the correct string of code for me?

I tried reinstalling but didn't work, what I did notice is that my boot partition in bios keep showing as Ubuntu, not sure if that matters as it boots manually just fine from grub.

I only forgot how my code looked like but I think it was in the quiet parentheses.

Comment: in that `/etc/default/grub` file, what is the value of `GRUB_DEFAULT` and what is the output of `sudo update-grub` - did you ever have Ubuntu installed on this system? Is it still installed on a different drive?

Comment: GRUB_DEFAULT=0.  , the output of update-grub says; found theme, found background, found Linux image, found initrd image, Warning Os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions. Systems on them will not be added to the grub boot configuration. Check grub_disable_os_prober documentation entry. Adding boot menu entry for uefi firmware settings...done. I might have installed Ubuntu in the past but I did automatic partitioning to overwrite the old install. Edit: I think it was Linux Mint that might use Ubuntu bootloader. I don't have any other OS installed or other drives.

Comment: @nick please ***[edit]*** your question to add extra information, don't put it in comments. Also, please consider using a normal operating system. Kali is _not_ a normal OS and shouldn't be used as a normal OS. It is a very limited tool specifically designed for security experts. Using it just makes things harder without any benefit. Anything Kali can do, you can do more easily with a regular distribution,  all you need to do is install the relevant tools. If you are not an expert, don't use Kali. https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/

Comment: If BIOS menus indicate `ubuntu` by name, that indicates you are using UEFI, and the installer has apparently failed to add Kali to the UEFI boot variables, or hasn't made it the first item in the boot order, and an old version left over by Ubuntu is getting booted. Please run `efibootmgr -v` as root, and add the output to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like grub is not installed correctly.  Grub is clearly configured, or `normal` wouldn't help.  So `update-grub` won't help you much since all it does is re-write the configuration.

Assuming you are booting with EFI, grub needs to be installed into your ESP (EFI) partition either along side a stub configuration file or with that configuration file pre-packed into the grub binary itself.

You say you can still get into your OS so, to fix this, boot into Kali.

Then, assuming your system boots with EFI not legacy, first make sure that `/etc/fstab` contains an entry to mount your ESP (EFI) partition to `/boot/efi`.  If it's not there then add it.

Then also check that your system has really mounted that partition with:

```bash
mount | grep /boot/efi
```

#### Try re-installing grub...

Once you know your ESP partition is correctly mounted then you should be able to just run `grub-install` with no arguments to add the correct `grub.cfg` file to your ESP partition:

```bash
grub-install
```

#### Otherwise manually install the configuration...

If that doesn't work then you may need to do this manually. Here my knowledge of Kali is a little limited so I'm not sure what the exact directory is.  You need to ensure there's a config file for grub in the same directory. Eg: if the boot loader is `/boot/efi/EFI/debian/grubx64.efi`, then there also should be `/boot/efi/EFI/debian/grub.cfg` config file.

You can edit this config file and copy in the exact commands you mentioned in the question:

```bash
set prefix=(hd0,gpt2)/boot/grub
set boot=(hd0,gpt2)
insmod normal
normal
```

**Better**, you can and should find your root filesystem's UUID (or the filesystem containing your /boot directory) and use a [`search`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/search.html).  You can use `blkid` to discover the UUID. Eg the config file might end up looking like this:

```bash
search --fs-uuid 917afb23-5bb6-4537-b985-3bc2a6416de0 --set boot
set prefix=${boot}/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```